# Error storing item cordova_not_available

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, ionic-native

I install [native Storage](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/native-storage/) By run these commands

```
$ ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-nativestorage
$ npm install --save @ionic-native/native-storage
```

[image]

And I have Import [native Storage](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/native-storage/) in app.module.ts

```
•••••
import { NativeStorage } from '@ionic-native/native-storage';
•••••

/* SOME CODE*/

providers: [
  •••••
  NativeStorage
  •••••
]
```

And I use it in my HomePage (`/pages/home/home`)

```
•••••
import { NativeStorage } from '@ionic-native/native-storage';
•••••

constructor(private nativeStorage: NativeStorage) {}

/* SOME CODE */
ngOnInit(){
this.nativeStorage.setItem('myitem', {property: 'value', anotherProperty: 'anotherValue'})
  .then(
    () => console.log('Stored item!'),
    error => console.error('Error storing item', error)
  );
}
```

But after all these steps I got error in the console

[image: Error storing item cordova_not_available]

my Question is **What do I do to avoid this Error** `Error storing item cordova_not_available`

Answer (score 1):

Cordova is not available when running the app in the browser. To use NativeStorage, just run the app on a device or emulator.

Comment: Cordova is available in the browser you can see [Supported platforms of NativeStorage](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/native-storage/#platforms)

Comment: It might work if you run the app with `ionic cordova run browser` instead of `ionic serve`. But I'd suggest [you check out this plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/storage/). Works great in the browser as well and better in general, at least in my experience.

Comment: I agree that `ionic cordova run browser` would solve this, but what if I am running ionic capacitor?